# Does Steam always show third-party DRM on the store page?

Tags: steam, drm

I generally avoid Steam games with third-party DRM due to issues the legacy copy protection schemes in particular can cause (see [a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1181116/is-it-true-that-starforce-drm-breaks-modern-windows-installations)).

[Resident Evil 7's Steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/418370/) as an example:

[image: RE7]

I'm fairly sure that the support is either **inadequate or up to the developers** (who may leave the DRM note out on purpose) as I have encountered Steam games that have some third-party protection according to [PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Home) and/or [ProtectionID](http://pid.gamecopyworld.com/) program (PC game "protection scanner") and no mention on the game's store page.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not. [Just Cause 3 uses Denuvo aswell](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Just_Cause_3), but it is not displayed on its [Steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/225540/Just_Cause_3/). Similarly, Steam does not always inform when third-party accounts are required either, see [Trackmania Stadium](http://store.steampowered.com/app/232910/TrackMania_Stadium/) that requires a ManiaPlanet account to play.

Steam has however improved in this regard over time and is informing its users more frequently of third-party requirements.

Comment: Sonic Mania had no Denuvo message on the Steam page, was added by the developer: http://steamcommunity.com/games/584400/announcements/detail/1448326045461380318